# Issue with changing working directory in VSCode Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, working-directory

Been trying to change my working directory in VScode.
My environment is the base Anaconda environment.

```
import os

os.getcwd()

>>> '/Users/hh'
```

I then change it to

```
os.chdir('/Users/hh/pywd/')

os.getcwd()

>>> '/Users/hh/pywd/'
```

But when I close down, restart VScode and run

```
import os

os.getcwd()
## I get the output below yet again

>>> '/Users/hh'
```

The wd is set to its previous state.

This is rather curious as I don't have the same issue with Spyder or JupyterLab.

Thankful for help.

Answer (score 0):

The path of vscode is based on the directory where the workspace is located.

When you close vscode , it will automatically return to the workspace directory instead of staying in the state at the end of the last run.

Although you restore the code at this time, you will not get the result of the last run.

This is also beneficial, which can ensure that the vscode will not be confused when searching path.